# Distribution of sum of Poisson random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Given $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d random variables that follow Poisson$(\lambda)$, I want to find $P(X + Y \leq t)$ for some $t$. I don't actually have a problem with doing this, but I want to know if I should consider the $\lambda$ parameter to be the same, or different? Like $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If they follow the same distribution, what is the point in having $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are i.i.d. Hence you should use the same $\lambda$.

Note that since $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X+Y$ is a poisson random variable with rate $2\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought but wanted to make sure